# Why KendoUI.Mvc.dll for Kendo when all can be done using Js?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo UI is a set of client library and consists of .js and .css. then why would you want to use a dll like KendoUI.Mvc.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a C# developer (say you're transitioning from Windows Forms) and you don't have experience with JavaScript/HTML5/CSS. It gives you the flexibility to develop a Kendo UI web application using C# Razor syntax without having to spend a lot of time learning.